# Concatenate two git repository histories

Tags: git, git-history-rewrite

I want to combine a cvs and a svn repository into a new git repo, without loosing history of course.  The catch is the svn repo is a direct continuation of the cvs repo historywise.  Someone just created the svn repo and clumsily added the last state from cvs without keeping any history.  The most recent sources are in svn.  I don't want to keep the old repos.

The history in graphics:

```
CVS: A - B - C
SVN: D - E - F - G
```

What I want:

```
GIT: A - B - C - D - E - F - G
```

I made a git repo from cvs with cvs2git, and another git repo from svn with `git svn clone` as outlined in http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git but just can't figure out how to combine the two.  I did this:

```
git clone cvs.git
cd cvs
git remote add svn ../../svn.git
git fetch svn
```

Now what? `git merge -s ours svn/master` seems to do what I want but does not create a linear history:

```
A - B - C - - - H'
               /
D - E - F - G /
```

Any experiments with `git rebase` didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.git/info/grafts`](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) to connect histories and then `git filter-branch` to make it permanent.
There is a some description how somebody done it: http://bugsquash.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/stitching-git-histories.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it.  I would have never found this myself.  I'll post an answer how I eventually did it.

Comment: @MichaelLemke Yes... `rebase` is a red herring - it works with diffs, and reapplies changesets, while grafts allow to manipulate history graph directly.

Comment: Actually, I never came across grafts before (with git that is).

Answer (score 2):

Using what kan wrote I came up with this solution:

```
git clone cvs.git
cd cvs
git remote add svn ../../svn.git
git fetch svn
```

Use `git log --all` to find the unconnected histories:

```
...
|
* ab42f52 2011-09-14 06:03:07 +0000 |  [svnuser]
|
* 1985b93 2011-09-14 06:00:00 +0000 | Migration from CVS [svnuser]

* 12e0ed4 2011-09-14 05:58:10 +0000 | *** empty log message *** (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) [cvsuser]
|
* 5060a7f 2011-04-18 14:07:03 +0000 | *** empty log message *** [cvsuser]
|
...
```

Find the full SHA1:

```
git show 1985b93
git show 12e0ed4
```

Create the graft:

```
echo 1985b9305ebc819e760f7ecf8e2abe7963eac055 12e0ed4c3dd75cec396a2d228825702eab73ba19 > .git/info/grafts
```

Now the histories are connected but not yet permanent:

```
|
* ab42f52 2011-09-14 06:03:07 +0000 |  [svnuser]
|
* 1985b93 2011-09-14 06:00:00 +0000 | Migration from CVS (grafted) [svnuser]
|
* 12e0ed4 2011-09-14 05:58:10 +0000 | *** empty log message *** (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) [cvsuser]
|
* 5060a7f 2011-04-18 14:07:03 +0000 | *** empty log message *** [cvsuser]
|
```

Make it permanent as shown in http://bugsquash.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/stitching-git-histories.html:

```
git branch svnmaster svn/master
git filter-branch -- 12e0ed4c3dd75cec396a2d228825702eab73ba19..svnmaster
```

This creates new commits but also leaves the original svn commits.  `git log --all` will show it:

```
* 849278b 2013-04-15 16:31:44 +0000 | Java 6 in Eclipse.  Deployed. (svnmaster) [svnuser]
|
...
|
* c33f7cc 2011-09-14 06:03:07 +0000 |  [svnuser]
|
* 7acb3ed 2011-09-14 06:00:00 +0000 | Migration from CVS [svnuser]
|
| * b3d5413 2013-04-15 16:31:44 +0000 | Java 6 in Eclipse.  Deployed. (svn/master, refs/original/refs/heads/svnmaster) [svnuser]
| |
...
| |
| * ab42f52 2011-09-14 06:03:07 +0000 |  [svnuser]
| |
| * 1985b93 2011-09-14 06:00:00 +0000 | Migration from CVS (grafted) [svnuser]
|/
|
* 12e0ed4 2011-09-14 05:58:10 +0000 | *** empty log message *** (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) [cvsuser]
|
* 5060a7f 2011-04-18 14:07:03 +0000 | *** empty log message *** [cvsuser]
|
```

Remove the graft, the duplicate history will be gone:

```
rm -r .git/info/grafts .git/refs/original
```

Clean up:

```
git reset --hard svnmaster
git branch -D svnmaster
```

And push:

```
git push
```

All done!