# Append a newer Git repo onto an older repo to combine both histories

Tags: git

I've got two related git repositories on GitHub that should really be one. How do I combine both projects into one project, in a way that satisfies the following context:

- Each repo currently only has a master branch.
- A is the older repo, B is the newer repo.
- A is the canonical repo (ie: repo A has the name that I ultimately want this tool to be called, so I want all future work, after B has been appended to A, to be done in repo A).
- After B has been appended to A, A should exist, B should be deleted.
- I don't want to put one repo as a subdirectory of the other, I want to combine the two repos as if they were one repo all along.
- I want this change to the git history of A to be permanent so that folks don't have to pull refs, but instead just clone the updated repo A and get everything as expected.
- There are 3 similar files between the two repos: `.gitignore`, `readme.md`, and `package.json`.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just copy the contents of B into A and overwrite/merge files manually? Does B's commit history need to be preserved?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy - Yes, B's commit history needs to be reserved.

Comment: Is there a single commit `aaa` in A which should be mapped to a commit `bbb` in B ?

Comment: @LeGEC - not sure what you mean by 'mapped', but the point is to append repo B's initial commit after repo A's last commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate two git repository histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056506/concatenate-two-git-repository-histories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clean way to do it:

## From your local A repository

```sh
git remote add b https://github.com/your-username/your-b-repo.git
git fetch b
git checkout -b b-master b/master
git rebase master
# fix conflicts if any
git checkout master
git merge b-master
git branch -d b-master
```

### Explanation

1. Add your secondary remote repository called `b` to the local primary repository
2. Fetch everything from it
3. Create a new local branch that matches the b/master called `b-master` and checkout to it
4. Place everything you did in the B repository after everything you did in the A repository using the `rebase` command

   1. Fix the conflits during the rebase
5. Checkout your `master` branch (on A)
6. merge the `master` branch (A) to the `b-master` branch (B)
7. Delete the now useless `b-master` branch

Comment: Holy smokes it worked!! I was surprised your method did not include `git replace --graft`, and `git filter-branch`, but it worked very well. Thanks very much for your input!

Comment: "My" method does exactly what you want to do: it literrally takes all the commits from `b` and puts them after the commits from `a`. This is the very definition of rebase. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- [merge the two repository history as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55886165/6309)
- once the commits of both repositories are interlaced, you can deal manually with the three common files in order to fix their content.

Comment: That only *displays* the two repositories interlaced, not merge them!

Comment: @SteeveDroz no, the goal is to rewrite with filter-branch the history of repo A by adding the commits from repo B.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I understood that big `filter-branch` command the wrong way.

Comment: @VonC - your approach is more similar to what I thought I'd be doing than the @SteeveDroz solution since it uses `git filter-branch`. The context you linked to is different than mine though, and I'm not sure how to wield `git filter-branch` in my case. I don't want each repo in its own subdirectory, rather I'm after a linear history where the last commit of repo A is the parent of the initial commit of repo B. Any input?

Comment: @BrianZelip The approach I link do *not* put each repository in their own directory, provided you don't use the --prefix option (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#Documentation/git-read-tree.txt---prefixltprefixgt)